# lateinit property binding has not been initialized android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

when I try to start my application it gives me this error

this is the code:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Data binding, you need to assign the `binding` variable a value before you can operate on it. Look into [Data binding docs here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#binding_data). Similar thing applies if you are using View binding ([View binding docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#activities)).

Example taken from the docs:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val binding: ActivityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(
            this, R.layout.activity_main)

    binding.user = User("Test", "User")
}
```

Comment: i can't use DataBindingUtil i don't know why

Comment: It's hard to tell why without seeing the code and errors - please provide more context. Have you determined if you try to use Data binding or View binding? What is defined in your `build.gradle`?

Comment: in my build.gandle there's view binding